# Alternate Units Import Excel to Tally

Tags: excel, xml, tally

How to import Purchase Invoices in Tally ERP having stockitems with alternate units from Excel (XLS file) or XML file?

Invoice 1 :
Item: U-Pins; Qty : 10000 Pcs 
Invoice 2 :
Item : U-Pins; Qty : 200 Cases (100 pcs in each case)

Herein, UOM (UNIT of measurement) are different and alternate unit is defined in Tally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import Purchase entries with alternate units into Tally ERP, you can use the underneath XML.

**1st Purchase entry - UOM is PCS**

Purchase entry with stockitems having unit of measurement as PCS

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <IMPORTDATA>
        <REQUESTDESC>
            <REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <IMPORTDUPS>Modify with new data</IMPORTDUPS>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
        </REQUESTDESC>
        <REQUESTDATA>
            <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
                <VOUCHER REMOTEID="udi-H6W7QN-1000001-Purchase-43191" VCHTYPE="Purchase" ACTION="CREATE"><ISOPTIONAL>No</ISOPTIONAL><GUID>udi-H6W7QN-1000001-Purchase-43191</GUID>
                    <DATE>01/04/2018</DATE>
                    <EFFECTIVEDATE>01/04/2018</EFFECTIVEDATE>
                    <VOUCHERTYPENAME>Purchase</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
                    <VOUCHERNUMBER>VCH-PURC-1</VOUCHERNUMBER>
                    <REFERENCE>INV-1</REFERENCE>
                    <POSCASHRECEIVED>0</POSCASHRECEIVED>
                    <ISINVOICE>Yes</ISINVOICE>
                    <PERSISTEDVIEW>Invoice Voucher View</PERSISTEDVIEW>
                    <DIFFACTUALQTY>No</DIFFACTUALQTY>
                    <UDF:REFERENCEDATE.LIST DESC="`ReferenceDate`" ISLIST="YES" TYPE="Date">
                        <UDF:REFERENCEDATE DESC="`ReferenceDate`">01/04/2018</UDF:REFERENCEDATE>
                    </UDF:REFERENCEDATE.LIST>
                    <REFERENCEDATE>01/04/2018</REFERENCEDATE>
                    <STATENAME>Gujarat</STATENAME>
                    <GSTREGISTRATIONTYPE>Unregistered</GSTREGISTRATIONTYPE>
                    <PARTYLEDGERNAME>Local Party [GST Test]</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
                    <BASICBASEPARTYNAME>Local Party [GST Test]</BASICBASEPARTYNAME>
                    <PARTYNAME>Local Party [GST Test]</PARTYNAME>
                    <BASICBUYERNAME>Local Party [GST Test]</BASICBUYERNAME>
                    <BASICORDERTERMS.LIST TYPE="String">
                    </BASICORDERTERMS.LIST>
                    <VATPARTYTRANSRETURNNUMBER>INV-1</VATPARTYTRANSRETURNNUMBER>
                    <VATPARTYTRANSRETURNDATE>01/04/2018</VATPARTYTRANSRETURNDATE>
                    <LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                        <LEDGERNAME>Local Party [GST Test]</LEDGERNAME>
                        <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                        <AMOUNT>11800</AMOUNT>
                        <BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                            <NAME>INV-1</NAME>
                            <BILLTYPE>New Ref</BILLTYPE>
                            <AMOUNT>11800</AMOUNT>
                        </BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                    </LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                    <LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                        <LEDGERNAME>CGST 9%</LEDGERNAME>
                        <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                        <AMOUNT>-900</AMOUNT>
                    </LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                    <LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                        <LEDGERNAME>SGST 9%</LEDGERNAME>
                        <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                        <AMOUNT>-900</AMOUNT>
                    </LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                    <ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.LIST>
                        <STOCKITEMNAME>U-Pins</STOCKITEMNAME>
                        <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                        <RATE>1/Nos</RATE>
                        <AMOUNT>-10000</AMOUNT>
                        <ACTUALQTY>10000 Nos</ACTUALQTY>
                        <BILLEDQTY>10000 Nos</BILLEDQTY>
                        <ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                            <LEDGERNAME>PURCHASE 18%</LEDGERNAME>
                            <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                            <AMOUNT>-10000</AMOUNT>
                            <RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                                <GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>Integrated Tax</GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>
                                <GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>Based on Value</GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>
                            </RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                            <RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                                <GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>Central Tax</GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>
                                <GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>Based on Value</GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>
                            </RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                            <RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                                <GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>State Tax</GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>
                                <GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>Based on Value</GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>
                            </RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                            <RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                                <GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>Cess</GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>
                                <GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>Based on Value</GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>
                            </RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                        </ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                        <BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                            <GODOWNNAME>Main Location</GODOWNNAME>
                            <DESTINATIONGODOWNNAME>Main Location</DESTINATIONGODOWNNAME>
                            <BATCHNAME>Primary Batch</BATCHNAME>
                            <AMOUNT>-10000</AMOUNT>
                            <ACTUALQTY>10000</ACTUALQTY>
                            <BILLEDQTY>10000</BILLEDQTY>
                        </BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                    </ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.LIST>
                    <ROWNO>3</ROWNO></VOUCHER>
            </TALLYMESSAGE>
        </REQUESTDATA>
    </IMPORTDATA>
</BODY>
```

**2nd Purchase entry - UOM is CASE**

Purchase entry with stockitems having unit of measurement as CASE
(where 1 CASE = 100 PCS)

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <IMPORTDATA>
        <REQUESTDESC>
            <REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <IMPORTDUPS>Modify with new data</IMPORTDUPS>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
        </REQUESTDESC>
        <REQUESTDATA>
            <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
                <VOUCHER REMOTEID="udi-H6W7QN-1000002-Purchase-43191" VCHTYPE="Purchase" ACTION="CREATE"><ISOPTIONAL>No</ISOPTIONAL><GUID>udi-H6W7QN-1000002-Purchase-43191</GUID>
                    <DATE>01/04/2018</DATE>
                    <EFFECTIVEDATE>01/04/2018</EFFECTIVEDATE>
                    <VOUCHERTYPENAME>Purchase</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
                    <VOUCHERNUMBER>VCH-PURC-2</VOUCHERNUMBER>
                    <REFERENCE>INV-2</REFERENCE>
                    <POSCASHRECEIVED>0</POSCASHRECEIVED>
                    <ISINVOICE>Yes</ISINVOICE>
                    <PERSISTEDVIEW>Invoice Voucher View</PERSISTEDVIEW>
                    <DIFFACTUALQTY>No</DIFFACTUALQTY>
                    <UDF:REFERENCEDATE.LIST DESC="`ReferenceDate`" ISLIST="YES" TYPE="Date">
                        <UDF:REFERENCEDATE DESC="`ReferenceDate`">01/04/2018</UDF:REFERENCEDATE>
                    </UDF:REFERENCEDATE.LIST>
                    <REFERENCEDATE>01/04/2018</REFERENCEDATE>
                    <STATENAME>Gujarat</STATENAME>
                    <GSTREGISTRATIONTYPE>Unregistered</GSTREGISTRATIONTYPE>
                    <PARTYLEDGERNAME>Local Party [GST Test]</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
                    <BASICBASEPARTYNAME>Local Party [GST Test]</BASICBASEPARTYNAME>
                    <PARTYNAME>Local Party [GST Test]</PARTYNAME>
                    <BASICBUYERNAME>Local Party [GST Test]</BASICBUYERNAME>
                    <BASICORDERTERMS.LIST TYPE="String">
                    </BASICORDERTERMS.LIST>
                    <VATPARTYTRANSRETURNNUMBER>INV-2</VATPARTYTRANSRETURNNUMBER>
                    <VATPARTYTRANSRETURNDATE>01/04/2018</VATPARTYTRANSRETURNDATE>
                    <LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                        <LEDGERNAME>Local Party [GST Test]</LEDGERNAME>
                        <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                        <AMOUNT>18880</AMOUNT>
                        <BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                            <NAME>INV-2</NAME>
                            <BILLTYPE>New Ref</BILLTYPE>
                            <AMOUNT>18880</AMOUNT>
                        </BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                    </LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                    <LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                        <LEDGERNAME>CGST 9%</LEDGERNAME>
                        <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                        <AMOUNT>-1440</AMOUNT>
                    </LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                    <LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                        <LEDGERNAME>SGST 9%</LEDGERNAME>
                        <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                        <AMOUNT>-1440</AMOUNT>
                    </LEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
                    <ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.LIST>
                        <STOCKITEMNAME>U-Pins</STOCKITEMNAME>
                        <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                        <RATE>80/Case</RATE>
                        <AMOUNT>-16000</AMOUNT>
                        <ACTUALQTY>200 Case</ACTUALQTY>
                        <BILLEDQTY>200 Case</BILLEDQTY>
                        <ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                            <LEDGERNAME>PURCHASE 18%</LEDGERNAME>
                            <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
                            <AMOUNT>-16000</AMOUNT>
                            <RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                                <GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>Integrated Tax</GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>
                                <GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>Based on Value</GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>
                            </RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                            <RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                                <GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>Central Tax</GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>
                                <GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>Based on Value</GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>
                            </RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                            <RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                                <GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>State Tax</GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>
                                <GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>Based on Value</GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>
                            </RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                            <RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                                <GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>Cess</GSTRATEDUTYHEAD>
                                <GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>Based on Value</GSTRATEVALUATIONTYPE>
                            </RATEDETAILS.LIST>
                        </ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                        <BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                            <GODOWNNAME>Main Location</GODOWNNAME>
                            <DESTINATIONGODOWNNAME>Main Location</DESTINATIONGODOWNNAME>
                            <BATCHNAME>Primary Batch</BATCHNAME>
                            <AMOUNT>-16000</AMOUNT>
                            <ACTUALQTY>200</ACTUALQTY>
                            <BILLEDQTY>200</BILLEDQTY>
                        </BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                    </ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.LIST>
                    <ROWNO>4</ROWNO></VOUCHER>
            </TALLYMESSAGE>
        </REQUESTDATA>
    </IMPORTDATA>
</BODY>
```

Note the tags ACTUALQTY and BILLEDQTY must contain the required UOM.

You can also use excel file and directly import excel data in Tally ERP using udiMagic. Excel Template Name: Vouchers-V10-Sales-Purchase-With-Stockitems-Advanced.xls. Read more at https://www.rtslink.com